# BasicJavaAlgorithm_BiggieSize

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write a Stream function that changes all positive numbers in the array to “big”.

Example: `makeItBig([-1,3,5,-5])` returns that same array, changed to `[-1,"big","big",-5]`.

So far, I end up with:

```
public static Object[] makeItBig(Object[] arr){
    List <Object> array = arr.stream().filter(nb->nb>0).forEach(nb -> “big”);
    return array;
}
```

I was reckonin' to use map() i/o or in addition of forEach()..

Comment: Tks for ur reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes here:

- You cannot call `.stream()` on an array, you need to use [`Arrays.stream(T[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D))
- [`.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) removes values from the stream, so negative numbers will not be in the result
- [`.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) does not return results; it's like a `for (T x : as)` loop, you need [`.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) for returning the modified values
- You cannot just compare objects with `>`: you need to cast to an `int` first
- A stream does not return a list; you need to collect it or call [`.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray())

I recommend you read the documentation for each function that you wish to use (searching 'java 8 functionName' is great), read the error messages that you get, and understand the different types you are using; you should be able to fix most problems you encounter in this way.

All together, modifying it becomes the following code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class MakeItBig {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] bigged = makeItBig(new Object[] { -1, 3, 5, -5 });
    for (Object o : bigged) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
  }

  public static Object[] makeItBig(Object[] arr){
    return Arrays
      .stream(arr)
      .map(x -> ((int)x > 0) ? "big" : x)
      .toArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tks for ur reply Billy !

Comment: @Kamilo This is not very safe, though. At least use an `int[]` instead of casting to `int`s.

Comment: @user Not safe, no, but I didn't want to change the method's signature. Of course, this could also be taken as a minimal example, where different types would be used rather than `int`s and `String`s.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not blaming you, I was just advising the OP to not use Object[]s when a more specific type is needed.